# What is the bash "test" command evaluation order?

Tags: bash

What is the order in which the `test` or `[` expressions are evaluated in a bash script? Is it the same as the order in which they are written? Are they all evaluated?

In the following example:

```
if [ expr1 -a -n expr2 ]
```

will *expr2* be evaluated if *expr1* is false?

Comment: The example does not parse in bash. -a checks for file existence, -n checks for non-zero-ness of a string. The example results in a "too many arguments" error.

Comment: I haven't found anything about evaluation order in the manpages of `bash` or `test`, so it seems to be implementation-dependent. Since `test` expressions never change state or raise an exception, the evaluation order and laziness doesn't matter.

Comment: @Bjoern, it parses fine. I'm not sure what bash you're running but it works okay under CygWin. It's an older style of test using `-a` to do "and".

Comment: @Bjoern: Yes, it parses fine, because -n is an unnary operator, so the equivalent in C would be `if (expr1 && !expr2)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's been a long time since I used that particular syntax. Nowadays, I prefer:

```
if [[ expr1 && -n expr2 ]]
```

since I *know* that these are short-circuited. The `bash` man page specifically states:

> The `&&` and `||` operators do not evaluate expression2 if the value of expression1 is sufficient to determine the return value of the entire conditional expression.

It doesn't appear to state clearly one way or the other for the `[` and `test` variant (using `-a`).

However, in the interests of furthering your knowledge and mine (and an indication as to why open source is a good thing), I went trolling through the `bash` source code.

It turns out that it's *not* short-circuited in that case. The particular pieces of code are (compressed a bit for readability):

```
static int or() {
    int value, v2;
    value = and();
    if (pos < argc && argv[pos][0] == '-'
      && argv[pos][1] == 'o' && !argv[pos][2])
    {
        advance (0);
        v2 = or();
        return (value || v2);
    }
    return (value);
}

static int and() {
    int value, v2;
    value = term();
    if (pos < argc && argv[pos][0] == '-'
      && argv[pos][1] == 'a' && !argv[pos][2])
    {
        advance (0);
        v2 = and();
        return (value && v2);
    }
    return (value);
}
```

You can see in both those cases that it continues to interpret the expressions regardless of the state of the first expression.

That was from `bash` 2.5 but I've just checked the 4.1 source as well and it hasn't changed. Source was pulled straight from the [horse's mouth](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/).

So. bottom line: it appears that all sub-expressions are evaluated when using `-a` and `-o` with `test` or `[`.